# Audio playing issues Angular

Tags: angularjs, html5-audio

I just started learning AngularJS and am facing an issue with audio playing. Here is part of my controller's code :

```
$scope.preview=function(id){
searchRequest.getSound(id).get().then(function(response){
  var audio = $("#player");
  $scope.link=response.data.preview;
  audio[0].pause();
  audio[0].load();
  audio[0].oncanplaythrough = audio[0].play();
  });
}
```

And HTML :

```
<audio controls id="player">
  <source ng-src='{{link | trustUrl}}' type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

It is actually supposed to set the new song's url every time I click on a different item and play it (I am not sure designing it the right way according to Angular, as I told you I just began). When I click for the first time on a song, the data binding has been well done and the source url has been modified  but the song doesn't get played. Then when I choose another item, it still sets the right url to the source but plays the previous one every time. Basically I need to click 2 times on a song to make it read.

Do you know how I could fix it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.preview=function(id){
searchRequest.getSound(id).get().then(function(response){
  var audio = $("#player");
  $scope.link=response.data.preview;
  audio[0].src = response.data.preview;
  audio[0].pause();
  audio[0].load();
  audio[0].oncanplaythrough = audio[0].play();
  });
}
```

should work as expected

Comment: It actually works with Firefox but doesn't with Chrome and Safari. I must have made a mistake somewhere else I guess